# I cannot record my FramLayout this code are whole screen record

Tags: android

```
private VirtualDisplay getVirtualDisplay() {
    screenDensity = mDisplayMetrics.densityDpi;
    int width = mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;

    return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
            width, height, screenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null /*Handler*/);
}
```

How to Record Frame Layout which is in my Main Activity as a video file

Answer (score 0):

use this link record all screen properly https://github.com/yrom/ScreenRecorder

Comment: only record my framlayout view not  all screen

Comment: MediaProjection Recorder only Record All Screen not any height and width.

Comment: i want to create video my frame layout